# Force jquery to use css3 for its effects

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to force jquery use CSS3 transitions for its fadeIn fadeOut effects?

It's a mobile only site so I'd like to squeeze as much performance as possible out of it.

Comment: You might want to check out zeptoJS for a lighter jQuery-like library.

Comment: I'd love to but it's incompatible with a lot of legacy code for the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First [Google result](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+css3+animation) is the [jQuery animate enhanced plugin](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/).

> Extend $.animate() to detect CSS transitions for Webkit, Mozilla and
>   Opera and convert animations automatically. Compatible with IE6+
>
> Properties supported: (more to come)
>
> - left/right : using translate(x, y) or translate3d(x, y, z)
> - top/bottom : using translate(x, y) or translate3d(x, y, z)
> - opacity
> - width
> - height

According to [this page](http://www.benbarnett.net/2010/09/01/enhancing-jquerys-animate-function-to-automatically-use-css3-transitions/#target), you should set the plugin's `useTranslate3d` option to `true` for smoother (hardware-accelerated) animation on iDevices.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe jQuery natively supports CSS3 transitions. There are a couple of plugins you can get which will do it for you, but I think they pretty much all fall back to using JS if CSS3 isn't available.

Browser detection may (unfortunately) be your friend here.